# iOS: shrink image and makes height : width = 1 : 1

Tags: ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

Here is a camera demo from iOS developer center, and the function used to shrink image is on below.
The problem what I met is image being stretched while its width < height.
However, I've need to scale and shrink the image into a square(width : height = 1 : 1).
Do anybody have solution on this?
Thanks you guys prompt helped in advance.

```
static UIImage *shrinkImage(UIImage *original, CGSize size) {
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, size.width * scale,
                                             size.height * scale, 8, 0, colorSpace,   kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGContextDrawImage(context,
                   CGRectMake(0, 0, original.size.width * scale, original.size.width * scale),
                   original.CGImage);
    CGImageRef shrunken = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *final = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:shrunken];

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGImageRelease(shrunken);   

    return final;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to clip the long part of the image?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    if(newSize.width > newSize.height)
      newSize = CGSizeMake(newSize.height, newSize.height);
    else
      newSize = CGSizeMake(newSize.width, newSize.width);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);    
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;    
}
```

If you are not going to maintain aspect ratio, your image will surely look stretched.